# Existing PBIX PBI file connect to Azure SQL database Power BI Service

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have an existing PBIX file that uses on-premise SQL server as data source and there is a gateway on PBI service for it. Now I want the same PBIX file to be able to use Azure SQL database as data source.

I am able to connect PBI desktop version to Azure SQL database, I published the report to power bi service.

As per my research we do not need a data gateway for Azure.

How do I set up Power BI service in order to connect to the power BI file? I put in the credentials as well and the report does not load.

Error shows as:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the Networking setting of your Azure SQL Server.  Either the firewall rules, or the "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" setting?

[screenshot of Networking tab of an Azure SQL Server in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsMTc.png)